# no persistent classes found for query class: FROM class models.AModel$ (hibernate 4 scala and play framework)

Tags: hibernate, scala, playframework-2.0, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I`m using the play framework (scala) with hibernate 4 (orm).

I created some models.. here my example model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aModel")  
class AModel {  

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  var id:Long = 0

  @OneToOne
  var contact:Contact = null

}
```

My DAO is inside the same file as my AModel class:

```
object AModel extends GenericDao(classOf[AModel]){
    def getAllModels():List[AModel] = {
      tx.begin
      val query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM " + classOf[AModel].getName)
      val result = query.getResultList.asInstanceOf[List[AModel]]
      tx.commit
      return result
    }
}
```

In my persistence.xml I map the AModel class as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="HibernateService">
    <description>
        Persistence unit
    </description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>models.AModel</class>
    <properties>
      <!-- all properties -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Still it sais that it cant find any suitable mapping. What am I doing wrong?

Here the output:

```
no persistent classes found for query class: FROM models.AModel$
```

I hope there is somebody able to help me. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Shouldn't it be just a `FROM AModel`?

Comment: No, but this doesnt matter.. with another query it is the same result

Comment: I just found out that there are no QueryTranslators in my Translator list. How can I set them?

Comment: I also found out that in the SessionFactoryImpl when it comes to the getImplementors() method, the given class name compared to the correct  QueryableEntityName is always false. class name is "models.AModel" and entity name is "models.AModel$". how can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error for this concrete issue. I used the objects (DAO) class name within the query. The solution was to switch to the class AModel! (Not the Object AModel)

No I have another issue..

I receive a hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: type of: models.AModel

Does anyone know anything about this exact error message?